# How to draw UIButton with shape as below?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I want to draw `UIButton` in following shape :

[image]

I have cut the image, so the edges are not straight. Please consider them straight. Also the bottom right corner is as shown. It is cut in quarter of circle.

I am not able to draw this shape for `UIButton`. How to do this?

Comment: just set the button type to custom and set this as the image?

Comment: If I set button as custom, it would be rectangular. Although it will be hidden but it won't be of same shape as that of image.

Comment: Are you talking about the touch area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. I did a search and found two simple solutions that seem much simpler than the GB2. They override either hitTest:withEvent: or pointInside:withEvent: to take into account if the current pixel is transparent or not. So just take your image, set the lower right corner to transparent in a graphics editor, and use one of these classes.

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/03/irregularly-shaped-uibuttons.html and
http://oleb.net/blog/2009/10/obshapedbutton-non-rectangular-buttons-on-the-iphone/

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myOddlyShapedImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: The shape should be of exact shape as that of image.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, I found a different UIBUtton libraries and solved this

search for:

GB2ShapeCache

and implement if you don't find it I could upload it and I give you the link.

You only put the library in your UIBUtton and it will work

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes please. Help will be appriciated.